# Anaconda ha dejado de funcionar

Tags: python

Anaconda dejo de funcionar. Simplemente darle click al icono de anaconda desde windows no hace nada. Si trato desde la terminal via teclear el comando:

anaconda-navigator

Lo que devuelve es lo siguiente:

> ```
> ""(base) C:\Users\HP>anaconda-navigator
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 10, in <module>
>     sys.exit(main())
>              ^^^^^^
>   File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 112, in main
>     clean_logs()
>   File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\logs\common.py", line 135, in clean_logs
>     lines = load_log(path)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\logs\common.py", line 158, in load_log
>     for line in stream:
>   File "<frozen codecs>", line 322, in decode
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 1653: invalid continuation byte""
> ```

Ya desinstale anaconda y la he vuelto a instalar, incluso borre los registros en regedit pero nada ha fucionado hasta ahora y desde la terminal sigue apareciendo el mismo error.

¿Alguien sabe cómo arreglarlo?

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la versión de Python? Pulsa en [edit] y agrégalo en tu pregunta, además de poner en el título el error _específico_. No olvides además de que mayúsculas sostenidas, en internet, es igual a GRITAR.

Comment: Hola, es la versión 3.11.5

Comment: Pudiera ser que algun archivo de log este corrupto, prueba con [anaconda-clean](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/uninstall/#full-uninstall) o elimina los archivos de log manualmente (ni idea donde los guarda en Windows....). Otra opción es que el interprete este usando el encoding incorrecto para leer los archivos, algún dia Windows usara UTF-8 por defecto como el resto y el mundo sera algo mejor...

Answer (score 0):

Desinstala anaconda y elimina todas las variables de entorno relacionadas. Después vuelve a instalarlo, suele dar conflictos si tienes variables de entorno de anaconda antiguas.